# Translucent colors in Java through properties files

Tags: java, properties, colors, transparency

Is it possible to specify a color in a properties file that has an alpha component?  When I put a hexadecimal number in the properties file that has an alpha channel, the alpha is ignored.  I notice that the [decode method of string](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29) says "Converts a String to an integer and returns the specified **opaque** Color.", and that [the only single argument constructor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int%29) that takes in an int or hexadecimal number also says that it's an opaque color.  What is the best practice in this regard?

The alternatives I see are to have something like

```
component.color.red=128
component.color.green=25
component.color.blue=54
component.color.alpha=244
```

or

```
component.color=128_25_54_244
```

and then manually splitting up the string into its constituent RGBA components.  Neither of these solutions looks very appealing to me.

I remember at one time I saw an alternative properties project, I think for swingx, that had better support for colors.  Does anyone know what that was, and whether it could solve my problem?

EDIT:

As I say in the comments to one of the posts, I want a solution where I can specify colors in whatever means I want in the properties file (hexadecimal for opaque colors, signed integer for translucent) and not have to change the source code that deals with interpreting the key/value pairs for the color.

Second Edit:
The library I was talking about is [Fuse](https://fuse.dev.java.net/), which is a resource injection framework for GUI programming.

Comment: To make sure I understand: if you want to set an opaque color, you want to do this:
component.color=0000FF //opaque blue
and to do a translucent, you want this:
component.color=1996553984 //translucent green

Correct? You can't store some in base 16 and some in base 10 and expect to read them and use them the same way. At some point you'll have to convert from one to the other.

Comment: I should have realized that - it can't magically know what to do with the string.

Perhaps I should keep all the numbers in hexadecimal RGB format, and if it's transparent, put it in hexadecimal RGBA format (or ARGB, doesn't really matter).  Then I would have to parse the string, see if it's longer than a certain length; if it is use the alpha channel, else do not.

Is there a better way?

Comment: The easiest way would be to store them all as ARGB, then you can parse and pass directly in. (prepend FF if it's an opaque color).

Comment: Sometimes the simple answer escapes me.  If you respond with that answer I will accept it and you'll get the bounty :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to store them all as ARGB, then you can parse and pass directly in. (prepend FF if it's an opaque color). Repost as answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Store the color as a full 32-bit int (use [Color.getRGB()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB%28%29)) and reconstitute the Color using [Color(int, true)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int,%20boolean%29)

This will make it hard to hand-edit the properties files since you'll see numbers like

```
somecolor = -123875123
```

Some more fun example code w/ output

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Color r = Color.red;
    int ir = r.getRGB();
    Color nr = new Color(ir, true);
    System.out.println(r + ":" + r.getAlpha() + ", " + ir + ", " + nr + ":" + nr.getAlpha());

    Color c = new Color(1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.5f);
    int ic = c.getRGB();
    Color nc = new Color(ic, true);
    System.out.println(c + ":" + c.getAlpha() + ", " + ic + ", " + nc + ":" + nc.getAlpha());
}
```

Output

```
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]:255, -65536, java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]:255
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=128,b=255]:128, -2130738945, java.awt.Color[r=255,g=128,b=255]:128
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I cannot use the same code for translucent and opaque colors.  For instance, if I specify my color as a standard opaque color FFFFFF, I need to make sure that I read the property file, parse the string using base 16.  If I have a translucent color I need to read the property file, parse the string using base 10.  I want a mechanism that will be the same in either case - when I change my properties file, I don't want to have to change any source code.

Comment: If you specify them both with hex, that will work. ie: FFFFFFFF for opaque or 77FFFFFF to specify translucent. then just use the Color(int, true) ctor. You could use a little trickery to see if there are only 6 digits, to just prepend the FF on the front.

Comment: I left out the hex conversion parts. In my application we write colors exactly as Kylar has indicated

Answer (score 1):

What about the [Color( int rgb, boolean hasAlpha )](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int,%20boolean%29) constructor.

It says that I will take  the alpha from the same number, that may work for you, just remember to set it to true always and for opaque colors use the 255